# What is the family of functions $f(x),g(x)$ such that $f/g=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, defined on $x\geq1$, we know
$$f(1)=g(1)=1$$
$$g,f>0$$
$$\frac{\text{d} f}{\text{d} x}\geq0,\quad\frac{\text{d} g}{\text{d} x}\leq0$$
and
$$\frac{f}{g}=x$$
for $x\geq1$.

My approach was this:

Clearly
$$f=xg$$
So we only need to define a general solution for $g$. Let us look for what exponent values, $n$, hold if we let
$$g=x^{-n}$$
giving
$$f=x^{1-n}$$
thefore we find that
$$0\geq g'=-nx^{-n-1}\Rightarrow n\geq 0$$
$$0\leq f'=(1-n)x^{-n}\Rightarrow 1\geq n$$
Therefore
$n\in[0,1]$. Are there any other possible solutions not of this form? I have tried a power series expansion, however this isn't greatly helpful as I have shown these functions behave nicely with non-integer exponents.

Comment: $$g_c(x) = \frac{1}{(1+\log x)^c}$$ for $0 < c \leqslant 1$ is another family.

Comment: Geometrically it's clear that there are all kinds of solutions, such as $x^a + c (\log x)^b$ for appropriate values of $a,b,c$. Linear combinations of solutions are also soluions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Not all $c$ will do here. With $c=2$ for example $f$ becomes _decreasing_ for $1\leq x\leq e$. The border case seems to be $c=1$.

Comment: @mickep Oops, that's what happens when differentiating in my head instead of on paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)=xg(x)$, then $f'(x)=xg'(x)+g(x)$ and since $f'(x)\ge0$ then $ xg'(x)+g(x) \ge0$ which implies that $xg'(x)\ge-g(x)$......(*)

Now since $x\ge 1$ and $g(x)\ge 0$ so that $xg(x)\ge0$, therefore from (*) we have, $\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\ge-\frac{1}{x} $$\Rightarrow$ $\ln g(x)\ge -\ln x $ $\Rightarrow$ $g(x) \ge\frac{1}{x}$.

Define a function $g(x)=\frac{a}{bx+c}$, where, $a=b+c$; $a,b,c>0$; $b+c\ge1$.
Then, clearly $g(x)= \frac{a}{bx+c}\ge\frac{1}{x}$, since $bx+c\ge x$ for all $x\ge 1$, we have $\frac{a}{bx+c}=\frac{b+c}{bx+c}\ge\frac{1}{x}$

$\Rightarrow $ $bx+cx \ge bx+c \Rightarrow x \ge 1$.

Now, at $x=1$, $g(1)=\frac{a}{b+c}=1$ iff $a=b+c$. Also, $g'(x)=-\frac{ab}{(bx+c)^2}\le 0$ iff $ab>0$

**Note:**
$ab<0$ is impossible case since when $ab<0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(b+c)b<0$ but $b+c\ge 1$ so that $b<0$ in this case $bx+c\ge bx+(1-b) = b(x-1)+1$ would be greater that $x$ iff $b(x-1)>x-1$ $\Rightarrow$ $b\ge 1$ which is a contradicts the assumption that ($b<0$).

Now, since $f(x)=xg(x)$, then we define $f$ to be $f(x)=\frac{ax}{bx+c}$, where $a,b,c$ are defined above.
$$f(x)=\frac{(b+c)x}{bx+c}\Rightarrow f(1)=1.$$ Also, $f'(x) = \frac{(bx+c)a-abx}{(bx+c)^2}$ would be $\ge$ than $0$ for all $x\ge 1$ iff $(bx+c)a-abx\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $abx+ac-abx\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$$ac=(b+c)c\ge c \ge 0$, (since $b+c\ge 1$).

Comment: Thanks for this analysis, it's nice to see another family of functions, the first 4 lines are some nice results, I have a question regarding how you defined your function for g(x), is there a more general form for this? I feel like you're immediately making it too specific, this choice of g(x) doesn't capture my result for instance, I am most interested in the choice for g(x) that yields the largest family of functions.

Comment: Welcome. If you need to extend the family of functions, you need to think about any differentiable function $g(x)$ such that $\frac{1}{g(x)}\le O(x)$, $g(1)=1$, $g(x)\ge 0$ and $g'\le 0$.

Comment: Note: Since $f=xg$ then $f'=xg'+g$, also, since $g'\le0$ therefore $xg'\le0$ for all $x\ge1$. As $g>0$ we have $xg'+g\le g$ which means that $f'=xg'+g\le g$ and this gives $f(x)\le \int{g(x)dx}$. On the other hand,  $\frac{f}{g}=x$ so that $\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}=1$ so that $f'g-fg'=g^2$ and since $g^2>0$ we have $f'g-fg'>0$ i.e., $\frac{f'}{f}>\frac{g'}{g}$ therefore, $f>g$. Combining these two fact we get that $$
 g\left( x \right) < f\left( x \right) \le \int {g\left( x \right)dx}  \\ \text{i.e.}\\
 \frac{{g\left( x \right)}}{x} < g\left( x \right) \le \frac{1}{x}\int {g\left( x \right)dx}  $$

Comment: Many thanks! This is very helpful!